# Excel numeric date encoding (UTC) to date conversion

Tags: r, excel, datetime

I can't seem to find the answers to this, I have tried multiple things - I am still very new to R.

I have two variables in a dataset `Old Data`

- `Open Date` - num from Excel and
- `Closed Date` - `POSIXct`, format: "2017-10-11 12:39:37"

I can't get them to subtract for each line within the dataset, the conversions seem to be off

This is what I am trying to do (without the syntax):

`Newdata <- Newtime = (Closed Date - Open Date) from Old Data`

Here is the `dput(Old Data)` results:

```
structure(list(open_date = c(43018, 43018, 43020, 43027), close_date = c("9/9/2018 12:11:11", 
"9/11/2018 13:21:11", "9/1/2018 14:31:41", "9/5/2018 15:44:41"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It would be great if you can share the data. Please provide the reproducible example!

Comment: I am sorry, but the data is propietiery

Comment: Make a fake data :)

Comment: 1. proprietary 2. you can rename variable names and multiply `rnorm()` to values. Without data no one can help you.

Comment: Time in Days Open Date (num  43018 43018 43020 43027 43022 ..) Closed Date (POSIXct, format: "2017-10-11 12:39:37" "2017-10-11 11:03:43" …)
2 9/9/2018 9/11/2018
4 9/1/2018 9/5/2018

Comment: And there are about 1000 rows in my dataset

Answer (score 1):

You can use `excel_numeric_to_date` function of `janitor` package to convert numeric Excel date format into `Date`, then use `mdy` function of `lubridate` package to conver character string into `Date`. Then you can calculate `difftime` period in days as below:

```
library(janitor)
library(lubridate)

df <- structure(list(open_date = c(43018, 43018, 43020, 43027), 
close_date = c("9/9/2018 12:11:11", 
"9/11/2018 13:21:11", "9/1/2018 14:31:41", "9/5/2018 15:44:41"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))

df$open_date <- excel_numeric_to_date(df$open_date)
df$close_date <- as_date(dmy_hms(df$close_date))
df$new_date_time <- df$close_date - df$open_date
df
```

Output:

```
   open_date close_date new_date_time
1 2017-10-10 2018-09-09      334 days
2 2017-10-10 2018-11-09      395 days
3 2017-10-12 2018-01-09       89 days
4 2017-10-19 2018-05-09      202 days
```